# Where does data() gets the data set description from?

Tags: r, package

Calling `data` without arguments produces a list of available data sets along with a short description of each one, for instance:

```
!> data()
 Data sets in package ‘datasets’:

 AirPassengers           Monthly Airline Passenger Numbers 1949-1960
 BJsales                 Sales Data with Leading Indicator
 BJsales.lead (BJsales)
                         Sales Data with Leading Indicator
 BOD                     Biochemical Oxygen Demand
 ...
```

I have written a package that includes some data files in Rda format (made with `save()`) in the package's `data/` directory, and while `data()` finds them, there's no
description.

```
!> data()
 Data sets in package ‘datasets’:

 AirPassengers           Monthly Airline Passenger Numbers 1949-1960
 BJsales                 Sales Data with Leading Indicator
 BJsales.lead (BJsales)
                         Sales Data with Leading Indicator
 BOD                     Biochemical Oxygen Demand
 ...

 Data sets in package ‘fbdata’:

 football.d1
 football.e0
 ...
```

How does one include a description for the data sets?

Comment: See http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html (Hadley's chapter on data in R packages that includes a section on documenting data sets).  Also re: where `data` finds info : _If no data sets are specified, data lists the available data sets. It looks for a new-style data index in the ‘Meta’ or, if this is not found, an old-style ‘00Index’ file in the ‘data’ directory of each specified package, and uses these files to prepare a listing. If there is a ‘data’ area but no index, available data files for loading are computed and included in the listing, and a warning is given: such packages are incomplete_

Comment: I read this before but I haven't found details on the specific format of these files. Now I've tried to put a 00Index file in the data directory but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `?promptData`, or the corresponding `roxygen2` markup, to generate the skeleton of an `Rd` file for your data set, then edit it appropriately to add a description, then rebuild the package ...

As @hrbrmaster points out above, if you *really* want to hack the data description, you can do something like this (example for the `plyr` package):

```
datadesc <- file.path(.libPaths()[1],"plyr","Meta","data.rds")
r <- readRDS(datadesc)
r
##      [,1]       [,2]                                                    
## [1,] "baseball" "Yearly batting records for all major league baseball players"
## [2,] "ozone"    "Monthly ozone measurements over Central America."
r[1,2] <- "hacked description"
saveRDS(r,datadesc)
```

... but I haven't actually tested this.

I don't know what your setup is, but I would argue that in the long run it's actually a lot safer to re-build and re-install the package regularly (wouldn't you like to change the version number so that you can tell easily what version of the data users have access to?) than to hack it in this way ...

Comment: Is it not possible to do it manually? I plan to generate the data files *after* the package is installed. I know this approach is unorthodox but since the data is updated on a weekly basis I see no other way around. I can't rebuild the package every week.